# jQuery Validate Custom Method Not Display Message

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I created a cutom jQuery validator Method called 'require' because I wanted to also add a red border when a required field is empty. The method added the red border successfully, but it did not display the error message. What did I do wrong?

**The first name input control**

```
<input type="text" name="firstName" class="form-control" id="fName" placeholder="First Name" />
```

**The jQuery Custom validator method.**

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("require", function (value, element, params) {
    var valid = false;
    if (!value) {
        $(element).addClass('invalid');
    } else {
        $(element).removeClass('invalid');
        valid = true;
    }
    return this.optional(element) || valid;
}, "Required field");
```

**The validator rule**

```
$('#newUsers').validate({
        rules: {
            firstName: {
              // required : true,
               maxlength: 50,
               require : '#firstName'
            },
          messages: {
            firstName: {
        //required: 'First name is required.'
                maxlength: 'First name cannot have more 50 letters',
                require: 'First name is required.'
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I created a cutom jQuery validator Method called 'require' because I wanted to also add a red border when a required field is empty.

You do not need to, **and should not**, write a whole new `required` rule to simply add a red border!  If you did this, then you'd basically be defeating most of the plugin's default functionality, and you'd have custom styling for only one rule and none of the others.

- You can simply use CSS to style the `error` class as you see fit.  DEMO 1: [jsfiddle.net/L61xec5x/](http://jsfiddle.net/L61xec5x/)

OR

- You can use the `errorClass` option to change the default error class into `invalid`.  DEMO 2:  [jsfiddle.net/L61xec5x/1](http://jsfiddle.net/L61xec5x/)

---

> The method added the red border successfully, but it did not display the error message. What did I do wrong?

Your custom method has this line...

```
return this.optional(element) || valid;
```

The `this.optional(element) ||` part will ensure that the rule is always optional.  In other words, it says to ignore this rule entirely whenever the field is left empty.  **You cannot use this for a `require` rule since a field can't be mandatory if it's optional whenever empty.**

DEMO 3:  [jsfiddle.net/L61xec5x/4/](http://jsfiddle.net/L61xec5x/4/)

I am only showing you how/why your code was not working.  The preferred method of changing the styling is to use CSS and/or the methods already built into the plugin.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working fiddle with your example code: https://jsfiddle.net/dreysolano/nnfp5h8j/

Aside from some possible syntax issues with your `.validate()` options, simply returning `valid` from your custom `require` method rather than `this.optional(element) || valid` seems to do the trick.

Comment: Thanks, It works with removing the valid. However, I added the red border using css as Sparky explained in his answer.

Answer (score 1):

this "require" method should come under your input class